# Can't open Software Center due to a malformed line

Tags: software-center

When I try to open Software Center, the icon blinks, but nothing happens.
When I type `sudo software-center` in my terminal I get:

```
2012-05-07 12:57:18,385 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.em - INFO - EM's: 17 15 21
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 151, in <module>
    app = SoftwareCenterAppGtk3(datadir, xapian_base_path, options, args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 213, in __init__
    self.cache.open()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 209, in open
    self._cache = apt.Cache(GtkMainIterationProgress())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 93, in __init__
    self.open(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 140, in open
    self._list.read_main_list()
SystemError: E:Malformed line 54 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)
```

I have Ubuntu 11.10. I am new to Linux.  Appreciate your help!!!

Comment: Does this problem happen even after restarting?

Comment: post your /etc/apt/sources.list

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem:

```
SystemError: E:Malformed line 54 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)
```

Do a

```
gksu gedit  /etc/apt/sources.list
```

from command line and locate line 54 and see if you can fix it. If unsure what is wrong add it to your question and we'll have a look at it.

Comment: When I typed in gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list, I got:  (gksu:2374): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:2374): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:2374): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:2374): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
     Thanks to all for your suggestions!! Elaine    Also want to mention that I can't install Skype or Google Earth--suppose it's all due to the same problem. Thanks again!!

Comment: Thank you, @Rinzwind.  Don't know how to fix the error on line 54.

Comment: Those 1st warnings we all have and are harmless. It should just open gedit with some lines though!! Otherwise do, from commandline, a `more /etc/apt/sources.list` and copy the outpot into your question.